# jquery show hide panel height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EL2RK/)

I have this jquery code to show and hide panel from left to right. My problem is `height: 100%` not working. When i resize the browser the panel should be touch the browser bottom. But it doesn't fit to the `bottom: 0px;`.

```
$(function(){
    $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
        $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=295"
          }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $(this).html('Hide').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {      
        $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=295"
          }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $(this).html('Show').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: are you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/EL2RK/6/

Comment: posted answer with the same

Answer (score 1):

To set the height of a DIV to 100%, you should also set the height of body and html to 100%, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/veritas87/EL2RK/7/

```
html, body { 
 height:100%;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
html, body, .panel, .contentHolder{height:100%;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EL2RK/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

height:*some height*px; in your .pannel CSS

Heres a JSfiddle with min-height from your previous example :)

http://jsfiddle.net/EL2RK/12/

```
.panel{
Min-height:121px;
}
```